# Prevent scrolling for a certain element?

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

I'm using jQuery `draggable`() on a certain DIV-element, so I can move it around freely.

The DIV is quit big, so scrollbars appear when a part of the DIV is outside of the visible area, but for *this* element this I would like to see no scrollbars appearing.

But I *do* want scrollbars to appear when *other* elements are outside the visible area (for example if the page is longer than the screen).

So my question is, is it possible to exclude a certain element from affecting the scrollbars ?

(I'm not asking to use overflow to hide the scrollbars, I only don't want a certain DIV to affect them)

Any idea?

Comment: What you can do is overflow-y: hidden; This should at least prevent Scrollbars at the bottom. If you give am Element overflow: hidden; it doesnt mean that the element can only be the height or width of your screen, so you can do that aswell. and i am pretty sure there is an event that gets fired when you start your drag, in that event you can add a class to the div and that class gives you overflow: hidden; at the end of dragging remove this class and is it back to standard

Comment: can you bind an on button press event to the mousedown, mousemove and have that event update the css of the container to scroll none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your draggable DIV can be wrapped into another div that won't allow scrollbars to be created.

```
<style>
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.draggable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1000px; /* simulating going over the edge of the page */
    left: 800px; /* simulating going over the edge of the page */
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #F00;
}
</style>    


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="draggable">
        Hello - No scrollbars created for me. :)
    </div>
</div>
```